# WordPress Not Using Template Files After Permalink Update

Tags: permalinks, templates, htaccess

I have a really weird issue that just occurred on a client site.

I updated the permalink structure from /%category%/%postname%/ to /%postname%/ and suddenly my pages don't respect templates and are defaulting to index.php.

What else is strange is index.php is attempting to display the latest blog post of the site and not the actually page you are on, for example /about-us/ is not using template-about.php it is using index.php with the latest blog post content.

I have deleted and rebuilt the htaccess file, flushed the rewrite rules and nothing is happening.

If I set permalinks to Default(/?p=123) the site works just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am at the end of this very large project and I have no idea what to do!

-d

Comment: Can we see a **live link** to the site in question? Also: please be sure that you are calling **`body_class()`** inside the HTML `<body>` tag. (This is *very important to resolving your issue*.)

Comment: Additional things to include in your question: 1) What **Theme** are you using? 2) What are your **Front Page** settings under `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading` ("Front page displays", "page on front", and "posts page") 3) What **custom page templates** do you have assigned to any relevant static pages (if any)?

Comment: Im using a custom theme.
The dev link is here - http://ehealth.cnkt.ca/  Click any top level nav item, the site is not picking up the assigned template files..

Comment: It is reverting to index.php   Keep in mind this just changed after I updated the permalinks. Front page is set to template-home.php

Comment: Please ensure `index.php` uses `body_class()`. Also: What are your Front Page settings?

Comment: Front page is set to use template-home.php  blog is not set.

Comment: How is front-page set to use "template-home.php"? In `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading` you select *actual static pages*, not page *templates*.

Comment: Ok, its set to home. It's nothing to do with that though... The site has been working fine for 5 months... until I updated the permalinks

Comment: So **Front Page** is set to display a **static page**, **page on front** is set to a static page named **home**, and **page for posts** is unset? Also: what **custom page template**, if any, is set for the static page **home**, and the static page **about-us**?

Comment: And one more: can you set permalinks to default, so we can see the normal/expected behavior? I'm trying to rule out any template and/or core settings issues that could potentially be causing the problem.

Comment: Hey Chip. Thanks for your help here. I decided to restore the DB from yesterday's backups.  For whats its worth I actually believe the issue was from a custo taxonomy I created named 'year'. Not sure, but I think it might be a reserved name for WP. Kind of like when you submit a form using the input #name. it will fail everytime.  thanks again.

Comment: Well, we tried... :)